# Using Javascript, Prevent Scroll on Empty URL Hash Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I want to detect hashchanges, and if the hash is empty, prevent it from scrolling to the top of the screen.

Here's what I have:

```
// Older version of jQuery, so can't use .on()
jQuery(window).bind("hashchange", function (e) {
    if (window.location.hash == "") e.preventdefault();
    else alert(window.location.hash);
});
```

Put that into your console, and you can see that it correctly detects hash changes and alerts if they are not just "#", but if you change it append "#" to your url, it still scrolls to the top.

How do I prevent the screen from going to the top of the page when you add an empty hash, "#", to your url?

Comment: that last sentence makes no sense to me :(

Comment: If you add # to the end of your url, it sends you back to the top of the screen, how do I prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

```
    $(function() {
        $('a').click(function(e) {
             var lnkHref = $(this).attr('href');
             if (lnkHref.substr(lnkHref.length - 1) == '#')
             {             
                 e.preventDefault();

                 // optional if you want to redirect still
                 var trimmedUrl = lnkHref.substr(0, lnkHref.length - 1);
                 document.location.href = trimmedUrl;
             }
        }); 
     })
```

Comment: My hash changes aren't triggered by clicks though, they happen in various different places. I want to track hashchange.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm having a hard time understanding the question then.  Perhaps it would be better to focus on why a hash is being added manually, or some other reason, to the end of the URL and address the issue there instead of trying to patch something that shouldn't be happening.